# Docker compose Unsupported config option for service volume mongodb

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to learn docker by reading the official documentation. I am on the task of Use Compose to develop locally. Trying to compose mongodb but I got an error

```
The Compose file './docker-compose.dev.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.volumes: 'mongodb'
```

here is docker-compose.dev.yml file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
 notes:
   build:
     context: .
   ports:
     - 8080:8080
     - 9229:9229
   environment:
     - SERVER_PORT=8080
     - DATABASE_CONNECTIONSTRING=mongodb://mongo:27017/notes
   volumes:
     - ./:/code
   command: npm run debug

 mongo:
   image: mongo:4.2.8
   ports:
     - 27017:27017
   volumes:
     - mongodb:/data/db
     - mongodb_config:/data/configdb
 volumes:
   mongodb:
   mongodb_config:
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a small mistake on your part, the volumes section of the `docker-compose.yaml` file is related to all services and not one in particular, because of how yaml files are formatted the indentation level matters a lot, in your example you didn't use the `volumes` parameter, instead you defined a service called `volumes` and services don't have a parameter called mongodb.

You have to simply decrease the identation level on the last 3 lines and it will work just fine.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.2.8
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb:/data/db
      - mongodb_config:/data/configdb
volumes:
  mongodb:
  mongodb_config:
```